GitHub Actions : Why are the outputs of my workflow empty objects?
I'm working on a GitHub Actions workflow where I need to start multiple EC2 instances and aggregate their outputs. However, I'm encountering an issue where the output is an empty object. Here is my current workflow configuration:
name: Start Runner
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      jobs:
        type: string
        description: "The jobs to launch"
        required: true
    outputs:
      runners:
        description: "The runners to launch in format / lint / tests runners"
        value: ${{ jobs.aggregate-runners.outputs.runners }}
      instances:
        description: "The EC2 instance IDs"
        value: ${{ jobs.aggregate-runners.outputs.instances }}

jobs:
  start-executioner:
    name: Start job self-hosted EC2 runner
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        job: ${{ fromJSON(inputs.jobs) }}
    steps:
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::x:role/github-action-role
          aws-region: eu-west-3

      - name: Start EC2 executioner
        id: start-ec2-executioner
        uses: machulav/ec2-github-runner@v2
        with:
          mode: start
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GH_API_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          ec2-image-id: ami-id
          ec2-instance-type: t3.nano
          subnet-id: subnet-id
          security-group-id: sg-id

      - name: Set outputs
        id: set-outputs
        run: |
          echo "${{ matrix.job }}-runner=${{ steps.start-ec2-executioner.outputs.label }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          echo "${{ matrix.job }}-instance=${{ steps.start-ec2-executioner.outputs.ec2-instance-id }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  print-executioners:
    name: Print executioners
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: start-executioner
    steps:
      - name: Print executioners
        run: |
          echo "Runners: ${{ needs.start-executioner.outputs.runners }}"
          echo "Instances: ${{ needs.start-executioner.outputs.instances }}"

The problem I'm facing is that the outputs runners and instances are empty when accessed in the print-executioners job. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm setting or accessing the outputs, but I can't figure out what it is.
Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
i'm trying to set different outputs for each ec2 instances, but i figure out thats not working...
I want to be able to get each outputs of start-executioner iteration, to make the workflow outputs all runners, and instances

Please show the missing job aggregate-runners
